# Can I modify a U.S. rental car reservation from one-way to round-trip (or vice versa) while the trip is in progress?

Tags: car-rentals

I want to rent a car in Maryland so I can drive to a car dealership in Ohio and test-drive a different vehicle.  If I choose to buy the vehicle from the dealer, I would like to drive it back home.  If I don't, then I will need to use the rental car to get back home.

When reserving a rental car, one has the choice of a round-trip or one-way rental, but you have to tell them *at the time you make the reservation*.  In this situation, I cannot do that because I won't know until I have arrived in Ohio and inspected the vehicle I am thinking of purchasing.

One solution I can think of is to book the rental car as a one-way trip, and if it turns out that I need to drive it back I will call the rental company and ask to modify it to a round-trip booking instead.

I could also book the first leg as a one-way trip, and then book a second one-way trip back if necessary.  But, that would massively increase the cost because I'd have to pay a one-way drop fee for both directions.

Is there some way to make this work?

Comment: I don’t think there’s a general answer here. Rental companies and even specific locations will have different abilities to accommodate this. You might need to phone the rental offices in the area and discuss your options.

Comment: One-way rentals are substantially more expensive than return-to-depot rentals. You might find it more cost effective to return the car to the place you rented it and go back on the bus to collect your purchase.

Comment: @Arthur'sPass Or take public transport to Ohio in the first place...

Comment: As a frequent traveler, my usual rental company allows me to change trips on the fly (so to speak) quite easily. But that may be a byproduct of having a corporate sponsored account with them ( which can also be used for personal travel with the same conditions).

Comment: I would prefer to take bus or train, but those take 14-16 hours(!) each way, whereas by car the journey is only five hours.